# Interesting thing about block captured value and dispatch_async

Tags: ios, objective-c, block

Today when I test some code with dispatch_async, I found a interesting thing, when I run some code like this:

```
static int temp = 1;
    dispatch_queue_t defaultBackgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0);
dispatch_async(defaultBackgroundQueue, ^{
        NSLog(@"blk 0 :%d", temp);
    });
    dispatch_async(defaultBackgroundQueue, ^{
        NSLog(@"blk 1 :%d", temp++);
    });
    dispatch_async(defaultBackgroundQueue, ^{
        NSLog(@"blk 2 :%d", temp);
    });
```

Guess what's the log is? It's very interesting, like this:

```
2016-02-29 21:39:40.700 GCDDemo[46594:3826498] blk 2 :2
2016-02-29 21:39:40.700 GCDDemo[46594:3826496] blk 1 :1
2016-02-29 21:39:40.696 GCDDemo[46594:3826495] blk 0 :1
```

> I have tried many times, even the third block finished firstly, the value of `temp` is `2`, before the `++` executed. Shouldn't it be `1` ?

After I converted the code into C++ using `clang`, nothing special, key code:

```
static void __main_block_func_1(struct __main_block_impl_1 *__cself) {
int *temp = __cself->temp; // bound by copy
        NSLog((NSString *)&__NSConstantStringImpl__var_folders_s6_v33rqm893pddvmp9w2hyfhtc0000gn_T_main_d902a1_mi_1, (*temp)++);
    } 

static int temp = 1;
dispatch_queue_t defaultBackgroundQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_BACKGROUND, 0);
dispatch_async(defaultBackgroundQueue, ((void (*)())&__main_block_impl_0((void *)__main_block_func_0, &__main_block_desc_0_DATA, &temp)));
dispatch_async(defaultBackgroundQueue, ((void (*)())&__main_block_impl_1((void *)__main_block_func_1, &__main_block_desc_1_DATA, &temp)));
dispatch_async(defaultBackgroundQueue, ((void (*)())&__main_block_impl_2((void *)__main_block_func_2, &__main_block_desc_2_DATA, &temp)));
```

You can give it a try yourself, I tested it on my Mac book pro, OS X 10.11,
Any one know something about this ? 
Thanks,

Comment: Interesting thing, have you tried putting some breakpoints to check what's the actual order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens here is the following:

The asynchronous threads do complete in a different order than what you see in the  the print/log statements meaning that the `NSLog` statement executes **after** any of the other threads which meanwhile already did manage to do a computation on the (shared) underlying value `temp` (this is probably due to the fact that the `NSLog` statement takes (considerably) more time to finish before any of the simple calculations from the other threads finish).

Boris also has a valid point, obviously, the threads do execute concurrently, I'm sure you are aware of that, but it's not always as obvious in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

`defaultBackgroundQueue` is concurrent, so you shouldn't relay on execution order. It's quite possible, that `temp++` is already executed, but `NSLog` from another block is not. If you want different behavior, use serial dispatch queue.

Answer (score 0):

After I change the `NSLog` to `printf`, and add a `sleep`:

```
dispatch_async(defaultBackgroundQueue, ^{
        sleep(1);
        printf("blk 0:%d\n", temp);
    });
    dispatch_async(defaultBackgroundQueue, ^{
        sleep(1);
        printf("blk 1:%d\n", temp++);
    });
    dispatch_async(defaultBackgroundQueue, ^{
        sleep(1);
        printf("blk 2:%d\n", temp);
    });
    dispatch_async(defaultBackgroundQueue, ^{
        sleep(1);
        printf("blk 3:%d\n", temp);
    });
```

the result changed:

```
blk 1:1
blk 0:2
blk 2:2
blk 3:2
```

so as @the_critic said, `NSLog` didn't mean the actually result.

Thanks,